# VS Code extension reopen current file with custom editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a VS Code extension defining a custom markdown editor and would like to register a hotkey that will reopen the currently active text editor with my custom editor (as long as the file is markdown).

I have it working with `vscode.openWith` but this opens a new tab. How can I instead replace the current tab? The closest I've found is `workbench.action.reopenWithEditor` but this opens the following dialog, I want to just directly open my custom editor.

```
uri = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri;
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.reopenWithEditor', uri, MarkdownEditorProvider.viewType);`
```

[image]

I don't see `reopenWithEditor` mentioned anywhere in the VS Code documentation (I went to check if its arguments could solve this). Where is this kind of thing documented? I only know it exists because I found it in the Command Palette and used `Copy Command ID`